# work around function template partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Can I make something like this working?

```
template <int N, int Y>
constexpr int f(char *(&arr)[Y])
{
    return N * f<N - 1, Y - 1>();
}

// Y must appear here too because it's used in parameters
// and if I remove this I get "no matching function" error
template <int N, int Y>
constexpr int f<1, 1>(char *(&arr)[Y]) // run this when Y == 0 and N == 0
{                 
    return 1;
}

int main() 
{
    size_t x = f<4,4>();
    printf("x = %zu\n", x);
}
```

Comment: @legends2k: It's a code example. The body of function itself may don't make much sense

Comment: You can't have an array of size 0, so if you need the `arr` parameter you need to specialise for something else - perhaps `Y` of `1`.  Further, the specialisation should be `template <>` (remove the `int N, int Y`).  And you'll need to provide an array, which should be interesting given the recursive nature of the call - you'll probably need to do a cast to a reference to a shorter array.

Comment: edited. I introduced this error due my last edit when I add a array as part of example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically three solution for partial function specialization (altho you seem to have full specialization):

```
std::enable_if / std::disable_if
```

eg:

```
template<int X, int Y>
typename std::enable_if<X == 0 && Y == 0>::type 
int f();
```

Delegate implementation to a struct (seems cleanest to me):

```
template<int X, int Y>
struct f_impl {
    int eval();
};

template<int X, int Y>
int f() {
    return f_impl<x,Y>::eval();
}
```

and then partially specializing implementation

```
template<>
struct f_impl<0,0>;
```

forwarding template args as magic functions args and then implementing overloads:

```
template<int X, int Y>
int f(mpl::int_<X>, mpl::int_<Y>);

int f(mpl::int_<0>, mpl::int_<0>);

template<int X, int Y>
int f() {
    f(mpl::int_<X>(), mpl::int_<Y>());
}
```

Refer to `boost::mpl` for more metaprogramming helpers, eg `mpl::identity` for wrapping types:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/mpl/doc/index.html